# boolean variable is acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery

First the code:

```
function searchItems(){
var noParameters = new Boolean(0);
var formFields = $('form')[0].elements;
for(i=0;1<formFields.length;i++){
    if(formFields[i].type == 'text'){
        if(!(formFields[i].value)){
            noParameters = 0;
        }
    }
}
alert(noParameters.valueOf());
}
```

This function is called on a form submit. It's purpose is to see if all form fields of type 'text' have no value (empty input boxes).

I do not get an alert when I think I should. The boolean variable is initialized when it is declared, so there is a value in it. The if statements all work as they should, I have checked repeatedly. The only error I have in my browser is "type is null or not an object" which is on the line comparing the form field type to 'text'.

I have tried different syntax for the alert with no success: noParameters.toString(), assigning noParameters.valueOf() to a variable and then alerting that, 'true' and 'false' instead of 0 and 1. Why does  my alert not show?

Comment: @arxanas: writing clean code that uses `false` is not that c00L

Comment: @arxanas I don't understand your question. The issue is either true or false: there is a value in the form fields or there is not. This is criteria for a boolean variable.

Comment: Seems like you have an infinite loop because of the typo `1<formFields.length`...

Comment: @Bergi No, I have tested that and there are only 10 elements in that array. 7 of type text, 3 of type button.

Comment: @zerkms Uh... what?  Sarcasm?

Comment: @JeffFabiny But 1 is still less than 10. And will always continue to be.

Comment: @zerkms Okay, just making sure. :p

Comment: @JeffFabiny - 10 items in the array, yes. And 1 is always less than 10, right? === infinite loop.

Comment: Don't use `i` use `index` it is easy to confuse `i` with `1` and `l`

Comment: Note that if you want a boolean just set it to `true` or `false`. When you set `noParameters = 0` you're setting it to the _number_ 0. `new Boolean()` is almost never useful, because `var b = new Boolean(false);` creates an _object_ and any object is truthy if used in a condition like `if(b)`.

Comment: @Hogan Despite what you say, i is the preferred index for 99% of programmers. If you use a monospace font to code, then you won't have any such problem.

Comment: @arxanas - And yet this is the exact mistake this programmer made.  I've made it too.  I don't use `i` because it has wasted many of my hours.  It will waste yours if you use it, but feel free to do something we know will cause bugs.

Comment: @Hogan - _Maybe_ one day it'll cause me grief, but I've gotten through the first twenty years of my programming career using `i` all the time and never had a problem mixing it up with `1`. Whatever the language de jour I always use a code editor with a monospace serif font (like Courier). On the other hand, the number `1` and letter `l` (lower-case L) look pretty much the same...

Comment: @nnnnnn - What works for you.  Sometimes we have to code for other people.  Personally, my eyes are not as they were when I was 21, reading from a slight distance can make `i` look like `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because the condition `1 < formFields.length` is always true. Yet, `i` gets increased every time, until `formFields[i]` evaluates to `null` and you get the exception because you can't access a `type` property of a non-object.

---

To your question: `new Boolean(0);` creates an absolutely unnecessary Object wrapper for the value `false`. Don't use it. Inside the loop, you eventually assign `0` to the variable. JavaScript is weak-typed so this is syntactically valid, but still odd.

Then, in the alert you use the `.valueOf()` method. For the number `0` this will work because it is implicitly converted to a `Number` instance, but uncommon as well. If you'd used just a boolean value, you would not need it.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in your loop: you said 'while' 1

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant

```
for(i=0;i<formFields.length;i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that you've got a typo with the number `1` in `1<formFields.length` where you should have the variable `i` as in `i<formFields.length`. But if your purpose is:

> *" to see if all form fields of type 'text' have no value (empty input boxes)."*

Then I would tidy up your function a little bit like this:

```
function searchItems(){
   var noParameters = true,
       formFields = $('form')[0].elements;
   for(i=0;i<formFields.length;i++){
      if(formFields[i].type == 'text' && formFields[i].value != ""){
         noParameters = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   alert(noParameters);
}
```

That is, as soon as any non-blank text field is found set `noParameters` to false and break out of the loop. And as I mentioned in a comment above, just use the primitive values `true` and `false`, don't use `new Boolean()`. Note that you don't need nested `if` statements: the `&&` operator uses short-circuit evaluation, so it will only test the right-hand condition if the left-hand condition is true.

Or, since your question is tagged with "jquery", the following is shorter (but less efficient at runtime):

```
function searchItems() {
   var noParameters = $('form input[type="text"]').filter(function(){
                         return this.value != "";
                      }).length === 0;

   alert(noParameters);
}
```

That is, if the set of inputs of type text that have a non-blank value has a length of 0 then you've got no parameters set...

Either way, at the point where you test the `.value` you might like to trim any whitespace, so that the user can't fool your code by entering nothing but spaces:

```
if(formFields[i].type == 'text' && formFields[i].value.replace(/\s/g,"") != "")
```